Why this error in Google Data fusion when trying to parse json
I am trying to parse a json data in Google Data Fusion. Every time I am trying to prse the json file using wrangler, it ends up giving me an error.
I am fetching the json data from Cloud storage.
My schema is in avro file as well. I cannot figure out the issue.
Please let me know if you need any information regarding the problem.

I presume you have configured the necessary permission from your Data Fusion instance to the Cloud Storage bucket where your JSON file is located. Based on the error you provided, there’s a good chance your JSON file doesn’t adhere to valid JSON syntax. Carefully compare your Avro schema  to the structure of your JSON data. Any mismatches will cause problems. Also, you might want to check the path to your JSON file in Cloud Storage within your Wrangler configuration.
Sharing this documentation that might be helpful to you.
